# Wwise, Resonance Audio and Unity Integration. Configure Wwise Resonance Audio Plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, plugins, propagation, resonance-audio

I have tried to get a response on Github but with no activity about this issue there I will ask here.

I have been following the documentation and I am stuck when I have imported the WwiseResonanceAudioRoom mixer effect on the bus in Wwise and I do not see anything in the properties. I am not sure if I am supposed to? Right after that part of the documentation is says "Note: If room properties are not configured, the room effects bus outputs silence." I was wondering if this was the case and yes it outputs silence. I even switched the effect to see if it will just pass audio and it does just not with the Room effect, so at least I know my routing is correct.

So now this leads up to my actual question. How do you configure the plugin?? I know there is some documentation but there is not one tutorial or a step by step for us non code savvy audio folk. I have spent the better half of my week trying to figure this out b/c frankly for the time being this is the only audio spatialization plugin that features both audio occlusion, obstruction and propagation within Wwise.

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had Room Effects with Resonance Audio working in another project last year, under its former name, GVR. There are no properties on the Room Effect itself. These effect settings and properties reside in the Unity Resonance prefabs.

I presume you've follow the latter tutorial on Room Effect here:
https://developers.google.com/resonance-audio/develop/wwise/getting-started

Then what you need to do is to add the Room Effect assets into your Unity project. The assets are found in the Resonance Audio zip package, next to the authoring and SDK files. Unzip the Unity stuff into your project, add a room Effect in your scene and you should be able to see the properties in the inspector of the room object?

Comment: Thank you! Yes I have followed that tut. See I had no idea that when I added the plugin via unity that unity was going to be the only place the properties show up. I thought because the properties were not present within Weise something was wrong. Looks like I am doing it right. I am unable to author it though I just get silence if the plugin is on the bus. I am going to try somethings and get back to you since I know the plugin is configured now.

Comment: I am now able to see the properties, thank you! Also I am now getting error indicating the plugin is not registered nor could not find the plugin? Have you encountered this in unity?

Comment: I am however one step closer. My plugin is not being registered in Unity BUT when I connect to the remote platform in Wwise the plugin will work in Unity!!! hmmmm got to figure out why they are not registering.

Comment: Quick Q after an answer.you have to hook up occlusion and obstruction via Wwise and not as shown in the unity setup here correct? https://developers.google.com/resonance-audio/develop/unity/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to Egil Sandfeld Here ! https://github.com/resonance-audio/resonance-audio-wwise-sdk/issues/2#issuecomment-367225550

To elaborate I had the SDKs implemented but I went ahead and replaced them anyways and it worked!